# Upgrading NC30 M16 C Compiler: va_arg issue

Tags: c++, c

In my NC30 M16C compiler version 5, I had the following macros used by previous programmer. We use this macros in the "printf()", "sprintf()" etc functions.

```
typedef unsigned char * va_list;
#define va_start( args, first ) args = (va_list) ( (unsigned short) &first + sizeof( first ) )
#define va_arg( args, type ) *( (type *) args )++
#define va_end( args )
```

When I compile this code with NC30 M16C compiler version 6, then it is giving me the error "Invalid lvalue".
Here is the part of the entire error message:

```
clib.c(253) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );
clib.c(293) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    fch = va_arg( args, far char * );
clib.c(299) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    nch = va_arg( args, char * );
clib.c(305) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );
clib.c(323) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    ulong = va_arg( args, unsigned long );
clib.c(341) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    llong = va_arg( args, unsigned long long );
clib.c(359) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    ulong = va_arg( args, unsigned long );
clib.c(377) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned short );
clib.c(382) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    ft = va_arg( args, float );
clib.c(519) :  C2694 (E) unknown variable source
===>    *source++ = zeropad ? '0' : ' ';
clib.c(527) :  C2694 (E) unknown variable source
===>    *source++ = '%';
clib.c(532) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    snum = va_arg( args, signed int );
clib.c(550) :  C2694 (E) unknown variable source
===>        *source++ = *tempptr;
clib.c(556) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    fch = va_arg( args, far char * );
clib.c(558) :  C2694 (E) unknown variable source
===>        *source++ = *fch++;
clib.c(564) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    nch = va_arg( args, char * );
clib.c(566) :  C2694 (E) unknown variable source
===>        *source++ = *nch++;
clib.c(572) :  C2700 (E) invalid lvalue
===>    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );
```

Here is one of the function in which we have used these micros. This function is the same function as "printf" but named it zwPrintf():

```
int zwPrintf( far char * format, ... ) {
    zwVAList args;
    unsigned int unum;
    unsigned char temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE + 1 ];      /* for formatting numbers (max length for long decimal) */
    unsigned char * tempptr;
    int zeropad, minfield, counter;
    far char * fch;
    char * nch;
    unsigned long ulong;
    int negative;
    float ft, mantissa;
    unsigned long long llong;
    //unsigned char mychar;
    //unsigned char *mychar_p;
    //unsigned int *mytest_p;

    va_start( args, format );

    while( *format ) {
        if( *format == '%' ) {
            format++;
            zeropad = 0;
            minfield = 0;
            negative = 0;
            if( *format == '0' )
                zeropad = 1;            /* we want zero padding to field width */
            while( *format >= '0' && *format <= '9' ) {
                /* we are specifying field width */
                minfield *= 10;
                minfield += *format - '0';
                format++;
            }
            if( minfield > FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ) {      /* we want a field width greater than our field buffer, pad misc */
                for( counter = 0; counter < minfield - FIELD_BUFF_SIZE; counter++ )
                    zwPutc( (unsigned char) ( zeropad ? '0' : ' ' ) );
                minfield = FIELD_BUFF_SIZE;
            }
            switch( *format ) {
                case '%':   /* literal % */
                    zwPutc( '%' );
                break;

                case 'd':   /* signed decimal output */
                    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );        /* pull unsigned, and do math ourselves (to avoid confusion) */

                    //mychar='a';
                    //mychar_p = &mychar;
                    //mytest_p = ((unsigned int*)mychar_p);
                    //mytest_p++;
                    //unum = *mytest_p;
                    //unum = (*((unsigned int*)args))++;
                    //unum = (*((unsigned int*)args))++;

                    /* convert to decimal (backward) */
                    if( unum >= 0x8000 ) {      /* number is -'ve */
                        negative = 1;
                        unum = ~unum + 1;           /* make number +'ve */
                    }

                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( unum )
                            *tempptr-- = ( unum % 10 ) + '0';
                        else {
                            if( negative && ( zeropad == 0 ) ) {
                                *tempptr-- = '-';
                                negative = 0;
                            }
                            else
                                *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        }
                        unum /= 10;
                        counter++;
                    } while( unum || counter < minfield );
                    /* output the string */
                    if( negative )
                        zwPutc( '-' );
                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
                break;

                case 's':   /* far char * */
                    fch = va_arg( args, far char * );
                    while( *fch )
                        zwPutc( *fch++ );
                break;

                case 'S':   /* near char * (extension) */
                    nch = va_arg( args, char * );
                    while( *nch )
                        zwPutc( *nch++ );
                break;

                case 'x':   /* hexadecimal */
                    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );
                    /* convert to hexadecimal (backward) */
                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( unum )
                            *tempptr-- = zwHexToAsc( (unsigned char) unum & 0x0F );
                        else
                            *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        unum >>= 4;
                        counter++;
                    } while( unum || counter < minfield );
                    /* output the string */
                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
                break;

                case 'i':   /* unsigned long int decimal (extension) */
                    ulong = va_arg( args, unsigned long );
                    /* convert to decimal (backward) */
                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( ulong )
                            *tempptr-- = (unsigned char)( ulong % 10 ) + '0';
                        else
                            *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        ulong /= 10;
                        counter++;
                    } while( ulong || counter < minfield );
                    /* output the string */
                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
                break;

                case 'L':   /* unsigned long long decimal (extension) */
                    llong = va_arg( args, unsigned long long );
                    /* convert to decimal (backward) */
                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( llong )
                            *tempptr-- = (unsigned char)( llong % 10 ) + '0';
                        else
                            *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        llong /= 10;
                        counter++;
                    } while( llong || counter < minfield );
                    /* output the string */
                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
                break;

                case 'h':   /* unsigned long int hexadecimal (extension) */
                    ulong = va_arg( args, unsigned long );
                    /* convert to hexadecimal (backward) */
                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( ulong )
                            *tempptr-- = zwHexToAsc( ( (unsigned char) ulong ) & 0x0F );
                        else
                            *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        ulong >>= 4;
                        counter++;
                    } while( ulong || counter < minfield );
                    /* output the string */
                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
                break;

                case 'c':
                    unum = va_arg( args, unsigned short );
                    zwPutc( (char) unum );
                break;

                case 'f':
                    ft = va_arg( args, float );
#if 0
                    /* convert to decimal (backward) */
                    if( ft < 0 ) {      /* number is -'ve */
                        negative = 1;
                        ft = -ft;
                    }

                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;

                    /* split float to integer and mantissa part */
                    ulong = ft / 1;
                    mantissa = ft - ( float )ulong;

                    /* get integer part */
                    do {
                        if( ulong ){
                            *tempptr-- = (unsigned char)( ulong % 10 ) + '0';
                        }
                        else {
                            *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        }
                        ulong /= 10;
                        counter++;
                    } while( ulong || counter < minfield );

                    if ( negative ) {
                        temp[ 0 ] = '-';
                        zwMemcpy( &temp[ 1 ], &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE - counter ], counter );        //change to right position
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else
                        zwMemcpy( &temp[ 0 ], &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE - counter ], counter );

                    temp[ counter++ ] = '.';                        

                    /* get mantissa part */
                    tempptr = &temp[ counter ];
                    do {
                        unum = ( mantissa * 10 ) / 1;
                        if( unum ){
                            *tempptr++ = (unsigned char)( unum ) + '0';     
                        }
                        else {
                            *tempptr++ = '0';   
                        }

                        mantissa = ( float ) ( mantissa * 10.0 - ( float )unum ) * 10.0;                        
                        counter++;
                    } while( mantissa > 0 || counter < minfield );


                    for( unum = 0; unum < counter; unum++ )
                        zwPutc( temp[ unum ] );

                    /* convert to decimal (backward) */
                    if( ft < 0 ) {      /* number is -'ve */
                        negative = 1;
                        ft = -ft;
                    }

                    tempptr = &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ];
                    counter = 0;
                    do {
                        if( ft >= 1.0 ){
                            *tempptr-- = ( ft % 10.0 ) + '0';
//                          *tempptr-- = ( ft * 10 - ( ( ft * 100 ) / 10 ) ) + '0';
                        }
                        else {
                            if( negative && ( zeropad == 0 ) ) {
                                *tempptr-- = '-';
                                negative = 0;
                            }
                            else
                                *tempptr-- = ( zeropad || counter == 0 ) ? '0' : ' ';
                        }
                        ft /= 10;
                        counter++;
                    } while( ft >= 1.0 || counter < minfield );

                    /* output the string */
                    if( negative )
                        zwPutc( '-' );

                    for( tempptr++; tempptr <= &temp[ FIELD_BUFF_SIZE ]; tempptr++ )
                        zwPutc( *tempptr );
#endif
                break;

                case 0:     /* end of string (malformed string anyway) */
                    va_end( args );
                    return -1;      /* error */
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            zwPutc( *format );

        format++;
    }

    va_end( args );

    return -1;
}
```

Please guide me, what should I do to correct this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code that invokes these macros. (I take it your implementation doesn't provide `<stdarg.h>`?)

Comment: Actually the error message is justified, gcc is lax with this but the result of a cast is not a lvalue so postfix ++ cannot be applied (constraint violation).

Comment: I have added one function in the original post which uses these micros. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to replace:

```
#define va_arg( args, type ) *( (type *) args )++
```

with

```
#define va_arg( args, type ) *( (type *) args ), args += sizeof (type)
```

Explanation:

You get the compilation error because this expression:

```
((type *) args )++
```

is invalid in C: the result of a cast is not a lvalue and the postfix `++` operator requires its operand to be a lvalue. A lot of compilers are lax with this constraint but apparently yours is not (or the new version is stricter).

Also note that the proposed workaround should work in you program with simple assignment expressions like:

```
unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );
```

because `=` has higher precedence than the comma operator.

**EDIT**:

another (maybe even better) solution: you should be able to bypass the fact the result of a cast is not a lvalue using this solution:

```
#define va_arg( args, type ) *( *(type **) &args )++
```

Comment: Your first suggestion returns the wrong value, you need something more like `#define va_arg(args,type)  (args += sizeof(type), ((type *)args)[-1])`

Comment: Thank you both.
I tried both. It compiled fine but does not display anything on my graphics LCD. May be because "printf", "sprintf" etc functions using these three macros. And something is still not right.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I think you didn't read the note just after the solution. I didn't add the parens between the whole macro expression on purpose: if the macro is used only with an expression like `unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int );` it will work because the assignment operation will be done with first operand of the comma operator. Of course with something more complex like: `unum = va_arg( args, unsigned int ) + something;` it should fail. The second suggestion in my answer does not have this problem.

Comment: @user977601 the fact you have nothing displayed could also be related to the HW access in the `zwPutc` function (called in `zwPrintf`). Check first that calling `zwPutc` function to display individual characters is working.